# Css alignment image overlap

Tags: html, css, angular

Can any one help me to fix the image overlap.

Please is the HTML bootstrap card:

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="card-columns">
<div *ngFor="let issues of IssuesList">
  <div class="card-deck">

      <div class="card">
          <div>
              <img src="assets/img/icons8-verified-account-64.png" class="verified">
            </div>
      <img class="card-img-top"
        src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/madrid.jpg" alt="Madrid">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Madrid</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2">Spain</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Madrid is home to two world-famous football clubs, Real Madrid and Atlético de Madrid.
          Due to its economic output, high standard of living, and market size, Madrid is considered the major
          financial centre of Southern Europe.</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link text-info">See Gallery</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 5 days ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css style:

```
 .verified
{
  position:absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 2;
  width:20%;
}
```

Output:
 [image]

Comment: Would need JSFiddle or something like that with css code.

Comment: What do you want and what do you mean by image overlap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about your badge not being visible whole time it is because there is no place left on top of the screen for them to be shown. To fix this push your `.card` down with `.margin-top`

```
.card {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Modify this value as you want to achieve desired look. If badges where not the problem come back so we can fix it

Comment: If I have four items in the list then the alignment it getting changed. I am using bootstrap card for UI design.

Comment: you need to remove ```<div class="card-columns">``` element from your HTML. it should look fine after that.